# What are these strange brown things coming out of plant soil?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, soil, plant-recommendations, bugs

I found these strange brown bugs coming out from my plants soil. I don't understand if these are soil mites or what. I found that 5 of my plants have the same problem. Same brown things coming out from soil. Can anyone please help me? Does anyone know what are these? And how to get rid of them?[image]

Comment: Are you using garden soil in your pots?